# Correct way to handle task cancelation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am experiencing some weird behaviour with a windows service application I am working on. This is my 1st dip into Tasks so I am on a steep learning curve and in need of some assistance as I know my issue is probably down to something I have misunderstood.

I have the following setup:

```
public partial class MyService 
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        MasterTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        MasterCancellationToken = MasterTokenSource.Token;

        //Begin tasks.                
        StartAllTasks();


        //This is the thread that is going to listen for updates in the database.
        Task MasterService = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!MasterCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //Sleep for the amount of time as determined in the DB
                Thread.Sleep(ServiceInstance.PollInterval * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Polled for changes");
                //Check service modules for changes as per DB config
                UpdateServiceModulePropertiesAndRunningTasks();
                //MasterTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
            MasterCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }, MasterCancellationToken);
    }

    private void StartAllTasks()
    {
        //Index pages task 
        ServiceModule PageIndexersm = ServiceInstance.GetServiceModule("PageIndexer");
        PageIndexer.StartNewInstance(PageIndexersm, ConfigInstance, MasterTokenSource);

        //There are other calls to other methods to do different things here but they all follow the same logic
    }

    private void UpdateServiceModulePropertiesAndRunningTasks()
    {
        //Get a fresh copy of the service instance, and compare to current values 
        ServiceInstance compareServiceInstance = new ServiceInstance(ConfigInstance.OneConnectionString, ConfigInstance.TwoConnectionString, ConfigInstance.ServiceName);

        foreach (ServiceModule NewServiceModuleItem in compareServiceInstance.AllServiceModules)
        {
            ServiceModule CurrentServiceModuleInstance = ServiceInstance.GetServiceModule(NewServiceModuleItem.ModuleName);

            if (!NewServiceModuleItem.Equals(CurrentServiceModuleInstance))
            {
                //Trigger changed event and pass new instance
                CurrentServiceModuleInstance.On_SomethingChanged(NewServiceModuleItem, MasterTokenSource);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PageIndexer
{
public ServiceConfig ServiceConfig { get; set; }
public ServiceModule ServiceModuleInstance { get; set; }
public Guid InstanceGUID { get; set; }
public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; set; }
public CancellationToken Token { get; set; }

public PageIndexer(ServiceModule PageIndexerServiceModule, ServiceConfig _ServiceConfig)
{
    ServiceModuleInstance = PageIndexerServiceModule;
    ServiceModuleInstance.SomethingChanged += ServiceModuleInstance_SomethingChanged;
    ServiceConfig = _ServiceConfig;
    InstanceGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
}

//This is the method called within the PageIndexer instance
private void ServiceModuleInstance_SomethingChanged(ServiceModule sm, CancellationTokenSource MasterCancelToken)
{
    Console.WriteLine(InstanceGUID + ": Something changed");

    TokenSource.Cancel();

    //Start new indexer instance            
    PageIndexer.StartNewInstance(sm, ServiceConfig, MasterCancelToken);
}

public void RunTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Page Indexing");
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (TokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(InstanceGUID + ": Page index CANCEL requested: " + TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested);
                TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            if (ServiceModuleInstance.ShouldTaskBeRun())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(InstanceGUID + ": RUNNING full index, Cancellation requested: " + TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested);
                RunFullIndex();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(InstanceGUID + ": SLEEPING, module off, Cancellation requested: " + TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested);
                //If the task should not be run then sleep for a bit to save resources
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }, TokenSource.Token);
}

public static void StartNewInstance(ServiceModule serviceModule, ServiceConfig eServiceConfig, CancellationTokenSource MasterCancellationToken)
{
    PageIndexer pageIndexerInstance = new PageIndexer(serviceModule, eServiceConfig);
    CancellationTokenSource NewInstanceCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    NewInstanceCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(MasterCancellationToken.Token);


    pageIndexerInstance.TokenSource = NewInstanceCancellationTokenSource;
    pageIndexerInstance.Token = pageIndexerInstance.TokenSource.Token;
    pageIndexerInstance.RunTask();


}
}
```

What I am seeing is that the cancel and start are working fine for me for the 1st change detected but subsequent cancels issued after other changes are not working. I can see the call to the event method happening, however, it appears to be calling on the original instance of the page indexer.

I am sure I have just got to a point where I have been going around so long I have made a complete mess, but I would be grateful for any guidance anyone can offer to get me back on the right track

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: The question is a bit unclear because there are many terms used that are not defined or visible in the code. What exactly is not working? Is the cancellation token ever being cancelled? It should shut down the MasterService task successfully.

Comment: Hi. Sorry this is tough to explain. So what I am getting is: the app is starting task A starts Something changes, so my on change trigger is called and task a token is cancelled. Task b is then started. All good so far and the expected behaviour. When a further change happens I am seeing that the on change event is triggered as expected and token cancel called but it appears to be against task a not b so what I get after a number of changes is multiple threads running as they do not get cancelled. I hope this helps but please let me know if not and I will try and explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken` can only be signaled once. They become cancelled forever. If you want multiple cancellation signals for multiple threads/tasks then you need one token for each such operation.

Often, it is a good pattern to group them in a class:

```
class MyOperation {
 Task task; //use this for waiting
 CancellationTokenSource cts; //use this for cancelling
}
```

That way there automatically is a 1:1 association of task and token. You are able to cancel a specific task this way.